# How to change typescript object type after adding new property

Tags: typescript

I have a node application getServerSideProps function with context object. I need to add new properties or parce data of this object. Is there a way to change typescript object type with minimal use of any and js code change?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-pOOHEe0c4SoQUpLiuSo8huSGIjIeqoUa+ZYqJUIdGpTLnlBDzyTa3YWGoZwet8umXNg8z2kgeBaOAJi3FAaCwHsaB4EQABWKDIgsFysJGGyfPoZq8IYIE6EAA).

```
// this type cannot be changed
type Complex = { very_complex_type: string}

// this type cannot be changed
type Req = {
  headers: Complex
  cookies: Complex
}

// this type cannot be changed
type Prisma = {
  db: Complex
}

type Ctx = Prisma & Req

// what type should i use for param, return and so on (without any if it can be done)
const ctxResolver = (ctx) => {
  ctx.db = { very_complex_type: 'smth'} // ctxResolver adds db property to ctx
}
    
const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: Req) => {
  ctxResolver(ctx)

  ctx // how to make it of type Req & Prisma
}
```

---

```
// Attempt 1
const ctxResolver1 = (ctx: Req): ctx is Ctx => {
  ((ctx as unknown) as Ctx).db = { very_complex_type: 'smth'} // to many type coversions
  return true
}

const getServerSideProps1 = (ctx: Req) => {
  if (!ctxResolver1(ctx)) return // i don't need if and return here

  ctx // ok
}
```

---

```
// Attempt 2
const ctxResolver2 = (ctx: Req): Ctx => {
  ((ctx as unknown) as Ctx).db = { very_complex_type: 'smth'} // to many type coversions
  
  return ctx as Ctx
}

const getServerSideProps2 = (_ctx: Req) => {
  const ctx = ctxResolver2(_ctx) // not sure if _ctx and ctx points to the same object in memory 

  ctx // ok
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish that `ctxResolver` only modifies props of an object passed as a param:

```js
const ctxResolver = (ctx: Prisma): void => {
  ctx.db = { very_complex_type: 'smth'} // ctxResolver adds db property to ctx
}
    
const getServerSideProps = async (_ctx: Ctx) => {
  ctxResolver(_ctx)

  _ctx // it stays Ctx
}
```

Comment: better, but i was hoping to not trick typescript :(

Comment: That's not a trick. `ctxResolver ` knows exactly only what it should know about `ctx` - `db` prop and that's all.

Comment: I oversimplified example, but ctxResolver also using data from Req. _ctx can be of two different types. _ctx is not of Ctx type, so it's feels wrong already, a hoped to change it step by step.

Comment: It'ok. Just unsimplify it a bit. I can remove my answer at the same time